# How to add StackExchange podcast to Google Listen (on Android)?

Tags: podcast, google-listen

I'm trying to add the StackExchange Podcast to Google Listen.

I've tried searching for it within Google Listen. No luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think: if you can find an RSS feed for it, you can add it to Google Reader, and put it in the "Listen Podcasts" folder.  That should make it magically sync on your phone.  I think.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the RSS feed before in Google Reader and it just subscribed me to the *blog*. So I tried it in Google Listen (on Android) and that worked!!

Comment: For anyone looking for it, the RSS feed for the podcasts is: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/feed/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any luck with that either.  What I ended up doing was downloading the MP3, putting that in Dropbox, then loading it up in Dropbox as a favorite (click the star icon).  Favoriting it makes sure it is in the offline cache.  Then I listen to it from there.  The downside is that Dropbox has to be open as it doesn't seem to support background audio playing.  The upside is that I can listen to the StackExchange Podcast in my car. :)